# Android: SearchView: How set individual icons for every item in suggestion list?

Tags: android

My fragment:

```
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE); 
searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));

searchView.setSuggestionsAdapter(new SearchCategorySuggestionsAdapter(getActivity()));
```

Here adapter code:

```
public class SearchCategorySuggestionsAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    private static final String[] columnNamesArray = {"_id", Category.ID, Category.NAME, ImageSource.URL};
    private static final String[] visibleColumnNamesArray = {Category.NAME};
    private static final int[] idsArray = {R.id.catalogNameTextView};

    private final static String TAG = SearchCategorySuggestionsAdapter.class.getName();

    public SearchCategorySuggestionsAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, R.layout.search_catalog_suggestion_item, null, visibleColumnNamesArray, idsArray, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint) {
       return new SuggestionsCursor(constraint);
    }

    private static class SuggestionsCursor extends AbstractCursor {
        private List<Category> findCatagoriesList = new ArrayList<>();

        private SuggestionsCursor(CharSequence constraint) {
            if (constraint != null) {
                findCatagoriesList = CategoryService.getCategoriesList(constraint.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return findCatagoriesList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String[] getColumnNames() {
            return columnNamesArray;
        }

        @Override
        public String getString(int column) {
            int rowNumber = getPosition();
            Category category = findCatagoriesList.get(rowNumber);
            if (column == getColumnIndex(Category.ID)) {
                return category.getId() + "";
            }
            return LocalizedStringUtil.getLocalizedStringValue(category.getName());
        }

        @Override
        public short getShort(int column) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int getInt(int column) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getLong(int column) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public float getFloat(int column) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public double getDouble(int column) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isNull(int column) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here **search_catalog_suggestion_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/standard_min_height_container">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/catalogImageView"
        android:layout_width="28dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/suggestion_icon"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_goneMarginStart="@dimen/standard_margin" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/catalogNameTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:text="Test text View Test text "
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/catalogImageView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/catalogImageView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/catalogImageView" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/divderTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/divider_color"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/catalogImageView"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/catalogNameTextView" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

As you can see,  set "**suggestion_icon**" in "**catalogImageView**"

Here result:

[image: suggestion]

As you can see all items in serachView's sugggestion list has same icon.

OK. It's work. Fine.

But now I need to set specific icon for every item it suggetsion list.
In this example: row "**Health**" must have one icon, "**Garden & DIY**" another icon and so on.

How I can do this in suggetsion list?

Answer (score 3):

Here my solution:

```
public class SearchCategorySuggestionsAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    // The Cursor must include a column named _id or this class will not work.
    private static final String[] columnNamesArray = {"_id", Category.ID, ImageSource.URL, Category.NAME};
    private static final String[] visibleColumnNamesArray = {ImageSource.URL, Category.NAME};
    private static final int[] idsArray = {R.id.categoryNameTextView};

    private final static String TAG = SearchCategorySuggestionsAdapter.class.getName();

    public SearchCategorySuggestionsAdapter(Context context) {
        // use custom layout because can not change text color on suggestion list by style.xml
        super(context, R.layout.search_category_suggestion_item, null, visibleColumnNamesArray, idsArray, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_category_suggestion_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(rowView);
        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        String referenceUrl = cursor.getString(2);
        String name = cursor.getString(3);
        viewHolder.categoryNameTextView.setText(name);
        Glide.with(context).load(referenceUrl).into(viewHolder.categoryImageView);
    }

    // Call on every press key. Constraint = null until constraint.length >= android:searchSuggestThreshold
    @Override
    public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint) {
        Debug.d(TAG, "runQueryOnBackgroundThread: constraint = " + constraint);
        return new SuggestionsCursor(constraint);
    }

    private static class SuggestionsCursor extends AbstractCursor {
        private List<Category> findCatagoriesList = new ArrayList<>();

        private SuggestionsCursor(CharSequence constraint) {
            Debug.d(TAG, "SuggestionsCursor(), constraint = " + constraint);
            if (constraint != null) {
                findCatagoriesList = CategoryService.getCategoriesList(constraint.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return findCatagoriesList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String[] getColumnNames() {
            return columnNamesArray;
        }

        @Override
        public String getString(int column) {
            int row = getPosition();
            Category category = findCatagoriesList.get(row);
            if (column == getColumnIndex(Category.ID)) {
                Debug.d(TAG, "getString: ---> category.getId()");
                return category.getId() + "";
            }
            String text = "";
            if (column == 2) {
                text = category.getImage().getFormats().getReference().getUrl();
            } else if (column == 3) {
                text = LocalizedStringUtil.getLocalizedStringValue(category.getName());
            }
            return text;
        }

        @Override
        public short getShort(int column) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public int getInt(int column) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public long getLong(int column) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public float getFloat(int column) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public double getDouble(int column) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isNull(int column) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        private ImageView categoryImageView;
        private TextView categoryNameTextView;

        private ViewHolder(View view) {
            //ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
            categoryImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.categoryImageView);
            categoryNameTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.categoryNameTextView);
        }
    }
}
```

And here result:

[image: searchview]

And now every item has individual icons.
Nice!